# Regex working on regex tester but not working for me

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this url:

```
http://example.com/categories/listing/all-categories?src=home
```

And I was testing online for regex [here](http://regexpal.com/) and ended up to this:

```
[^/]*(?=\?)
```

I want the part between asterisk `http://example.com/categories/listing/*all-categories*?src=home`

In my javascript I wrote this:

```
var reg = /[^\/]*(?=\?)/i;
var url = document.location.href;
var subcat = reg.exec(url);
alert(subcat);
```

But nothing alerts, what I doing wrong?

Comment: This regex works with me!

Comment: I think your problem is with `document.location.href`. What does `alert(url)` give?

Comment: Also, you don't need to escape the `/` inside the character class, and  the case insensitive flag does not do anything here either. This will not fix your problem, just a note. So it can be simplified to: `/[^/]*(?=\?)/`

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: The `/` must always be escaped within a JavaScript regex literal. Otherwise it would be interpreted as a regex delimiter, causing a Syntax Error. The `/i` is indeed superfluous.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Not inside a character class. Only `^`, `\`, `]` and `-` should be escaped. Did you try the regex I posted, no syntax error. More on it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: Hmm, interesting. You're right, it works (http://jsfiddle.net/4824e/1/), even though the syntax highlighter is thrown off track, and RegexBuddy always escapes slashes within character classes as well when using the JavaScript flavor. Thanks for making me check my assumptions :)

Answer (score 2):

this is working for me

```
var reg = /[^\/]*(?=\?)/i;
var url = "http://example.com/categories/listing/all-categories?src=home";
var subcat = reg.exec(url);
console.log(subcat);
```

i think your `document.location.href` is something else, please check it